# pgmagick on Google AppEngine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, pgmagick

I am trying to use pgmagick on Google AppEngine. I have dropped pgmagick 0.5.10 directory (containing **init**.py, _version.py, api.py) in main AppEngine directory. I can deploy the app successfully on Google AppEngine but it fails on the import pgmagick since **init**.py is trying to import _pgmagick which is not present.

File "/Users/user/app/pgmagick/pgmagick/**init**.py", line 1, in 
       from pgmagick import _pgmagick
   ImportError: cannot import name _pgmagick

Am I missing some additional pgmagick libs and where can I get them from?

Comment: Maybe its trying to use C libraries which are not allowed on gae?

Comment: Correct. It is C libraries =(. I am going to try Amazon Elastic Beanstalk =/.. Thanks

Comment: Try to use pure python version if it exists, also you can use Managed VMs to run python with custom C libs.